# How to automate hierarchical grouping of variables based on variable name

Tags: r

I have my variables named in little-endian fashion, separated by periods.

I'd like to create index variables for each different level and get summary output for the variables at each level, but I'm getting stuck at the first step trying to break apart my variables and put them in a table to start working with them:

Variable naming convention:

- Environment.Construct.Subconstruct_1.subconstruct_i.#.Short_Name

Example:

```
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(
  ph1.career_interest.delight.1.Friendly=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
  ph1.career_interest.delight.2.Advantagious=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
  ph1.career_interest.philosophy.1.Meaningful_Difference=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
  ph1.career_interest.philosophy.2.Enable_Work=sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE)
)

# create list of variable names
names <-  as.list(colnames( dat ))
## Try to create a heirarchy of variables: Step 1: Create matrix
heir <- as.matrix(strsplit(names,".", fixed = TRUE))
```

I've gone through a couple iterations but it still returns an error:

```
Error in strsplit(names, ".", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping with `as.list`, directly use the `colnames` because according to `?strsplit`, the input `x` would be

> x - character vector, each element of which is to be split. Other inputs, including a factor, will give an error.

Thus, if it is a `list`, it is not the expected input class for `strsplit`

```
nm1 <- colnames(dat)
strsplit(nm1, ".", fixed = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "ph1"             "career_interest" "delight"         "1"               "Friendly"       

#[[2]]
#[1] "ph1"             "career_interest" "delight"         "2"               "Advantagious"   

#[[3]]
#[1] "ph1"                   "career_interest"       "philosophy"            "1"                     "Meaningful_Difference"

#[[4]]
#[1] "ph1"             "career_interest" "philosophy"      "2"               "Enable_Work"
```

Output is a `list` of `vector`s.   It is not clear from the OP's post about the expected output format.  If we need a `matrix` or `data.frame`, can `rbind` those `list` elements (assuming they have the same `length`)

```
 m1 <-  do.call(rbind, strsplit(nm1, ".", fixed = TRUE))
```

returns a `matrix`

Or can convert to `data.frame` with `rbind.data.frame`

NOTE: `names` is a function name.  It is better not to assign object names with function names

#### Update

If the `lengths` are not the same, an option is to pad `NA` at the end for those elements with less `length`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(nm1, ".", fixed = TRUE)
lst1[[1]] <- lst1[[1]][1:3] # making lengths different
mx  <- max(lengths(lst1))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
#   [,1]  [,2]              [,3]         [,4] [,5]                   
#[1,] "ph1" "career_interest" "delight"    NA   NA                     
#[2,] "ph1" "career_interest" "delight"    "2"  "Advantagious"         
#[3,] "ph1" "career_interest" "philosophy" "1"  "Meaningful_Difference"
#[4,] "ph1" "career_interest" "philosophy" "2"  "Enable_Work"
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great when the lengths are the same. When they are not the same, it gives an error as you mentioned, "Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)" -  it looks like it rolls over and puts the left-most value into blank spaces...

Comment: @Josh I assumed that the lengths are same.  If not, then do you want to pad `NA` at the end for those elements having less length

Comment: @Josh you can try with the updated code at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can count number of `'.'` in the column names to count number of new columns to create. We can then use `tidyr::separate` to divide data into `n` new columns splitting on `.`.

```
#Changing 1st column name to make length unequal
names(dat)[1] <- 'ph1.career_interest.delight.1'
#Number of new columns to be created
n <- max(stringr::str_count(names(dat), '\\.')) + 1
tidyr::separate(data.frame(name = names(dat)), name, 
                paste0('col', seq_len(n)), sep = '\\.', fill = 'right')

#  col1            col2       col3 col4                  col5
#1  ph1 career_interest    delight    1                  <NA>
#2  ph1 career_interest    delight    2          Advantagious
#3  ph1 career_interest philosophy    1 Meaningful_Difference
#4  ph1 career_interest philosophy    2           Enable_Work
```